# Same user can not open application in more than two tab on same browser and same server

Tags: asp.net

My question is same user can not open same application in more than two tabs in same browser and same server.
For example , two users of  gmail account. first is abc@gmail.com and second is xyz@gmail.com.
So this both user can not open gmail account in same browser and same server at a time 
if in internet explorer abc@gmailo.com already login and then xyz@gmail.com will try for second tab  in entenet explorer for login   then automatically abc@gmail.com account will open .

I want to provide this functionality in my project.
In my project suppose abc.com login and anyone want to login in same browser on same server than he/she can login, so how to restrict them.
if i will match server or computer name then is it possible ?
Please give me answer for this .

in my application one user abc is login and url path like this  "http://localhost:2782/Viewer.aspx"
and after he/she open second tab and paste this path in url then secondtime his account will be open, and after in second tab he logout and then again login with differen username like xyz.com then this xyz.com will be open. so my task is in that application is restict the user for can not open same application in same browser in same server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question what you want to do, but here's some information, if it helps:

***A "user session" is established for each browser window, not for each browser tab.***

So, it's not possible to open a different session for two different tabs in the same browser window at the same time.

This is a basic design feature of browsers, and is what your users will expect: so your application and use case should be designed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit opening a several tabs in the same browser because a session is shared among all the tabs.

But you can restrict usage of only one browser, allowing only one user to be logged-in in the same time (uniqueness of session id among the application).